# Animate gravity layout changes of FloatingActionButton in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a `TabLayout` with 2 tabs besides `FloatingActionButton`. On switching tabs, I can change the `layout_gravity` of `FloatingActionButton` from left to right and vice versa. I want to animate this button (show movement from left to right or right left)  just like Android new phone book dialer floating button when it moves from center to right.

This is how I am changing the gravity.

```
 @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams( CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(16,16,16,16);

            if(position == 0){
                params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.START;
            }else if(position == 1){
                params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.END;
            }
            fab.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
```

[image]